# restful service on jboss as7.1.1 start up

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I would like some clarification on how a restful service deployed on a servlet starts up. Currently I am using JBOSS AS7.1.1 which includes resteasy. Below my web.xml is like

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

It would be great to know the use of the above code when Jboss service start up.

Thanks,
Ashley

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately you don't even need web.xml anymore and you certainly don't need the above configuration.  The only file needed to get JAX-RS going is something like:

`RestApplication.java`

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 * Used to bootstrap JAX-RS.  Otherwise this class is
 * not directly used.
 *
 */
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplicationConfig extends Application {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

After that, you'll create your service:

`HelloWorld.java`

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    @GET
    public Response getHeartBeat() {
        return Response.ok("Hi There").build();
    }
}
```

This service would then be callable at something like `http://localhost:8080/app-name/api/hello` where `app-name` is the name of your web application (assuming it isn't deployed to `/`).